# What is the distinction (if any) between a binary operation and a binary operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

Pretty straight forward. Just getting comfortable with Group Theory and trying to make sure all distinctions are crystal clear.

Is a binary operation just the concept/what is being performed, and the operator just the symbolic notation tied to said concept?

Answer (score 2):

Operator and operation mean the same thing in this context, just like one can encounter the two words map and function interchangeably in linear algebra and topology.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification